# Отсортировать список при этом убирая повторяющиеся числа

Tags: python, python-3.x, сортировка

Дан список заполненный случайным образом, где некоторые числа могут повторяться. Получите отсортированный список с числами без повторений.
Я сначала удаляю дубликаты, а затем сортирую вставкой.
Я так полагаю что это плохое решение.
Подскажите как удалять дубликаты сразу во время сортировки.

```
def insertion_sort_no_double(lst):
    for i in lst:
        while lst.count(i) > 1:
            lst.remove(i)
    for i in range(1, len(lst)):
        item_to_insert = lst[i]
        j = i - 1
        while j >= 0 and lst[j] > item_to_insert:
            lst[j + 1] = lst[j]
            j -= 1
        lst[j + 1] = item_to_insert
    return lst
```

И еще вопрос. Какая сложность этого алгоритма?

Comment: Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Answer (score 2):

1. сортируем список

   ```
    arr.sorted()
   ```
2. собираем значения, которые отличные от предыдущих

   ```
    new = arr[0] + [for i in range(1, len(arr) if arr[i] != arr[i - 1])
   ```

сложность алгоритма - это сложность сортировки, скорее всего O(nlog(n)) + сложность обхода массива O(n) итого получается O(nlog(n))

Answer (score 1):

Как то все неимоверно сложно. Вот так думаю будет намного проще, т.е. в две строки:

```
lst=[1,2,3,4,3,2,3,5,6,7,4,5,3,7,8]
st_lst=set(lst)
new_lst=sorted(list(st_lst))
print (new_lst)
```

Результат:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Comment: Зачем Вам множество преобразовывать в список? Множество уже итерируемый объект.
`array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 4, 5, 3, 7, 8]`
`print(sorted(set(array)))`